# Increase the size of C Drive in Windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

my question is already asked here, but it is closed without any answer.
[Extend Size of C drive in windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1256361/extend-size-of-c-drive-in-windows-10)

my problem is in my PC I have C,D,E drives. Drive C and D are almost full and Drive E has 100GB space available. now, I wanted this available space remove from E drive and used to extend the C drive so, my OS run faster than now.

I have google many times but they all said to use software to do this.but I want to do it without any software.and I also try to do it by shrink the space from E drive then I got unallocated space. when I try to Extend C drive it need unallocated space right side of C drive and I have it right side of E drive so I can not extend the C drive.

I have done shrink process by right clicking in my computer and then go to manage and then Disk Management. from here I have tried.

My Question is if software can extend the size of C drive then why we not extend it without using the software.

I want to extend my C drive without using any kind of software. Please, help me to get out of rid.

this is software link, 
https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/merge-non-adjacent-partitions-windows-10.html

thanks in advance.

Comment: software is chargable so I want to get rid of them

Comment: Why is there a link to a company who has known to spam this community contained in this question?

Comment: what you saying? as per my understanding I should not share software link?

Comment: I have share link of partition software because here this question asked earlier and in comment people have asked to share it so.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to expand your c drive? If it's full and you need the space (software install /patching /etc) I can understand that, but making the partition bigger, while not affecting the overall drive usage will most likely do very little to make the os faster.

Comment: os operated very slow so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you do not want additional software because it is "chargeable" you say, but [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) is free and can perform all the partition resizing acrobatics you want to perform in order to increase the size of your C: drive. You can use it to take space back from E: and give it to C:. It is the tool of choice for a great many techies and it is very reliable. I have used it many times to perform the very task you are wanting here, and I have done so without having backups of the data. I've never lost any files. Of course, you do so at your own risk. But MiniTool or something like it ought to have been bundled with Windows. It is that practical and essential. Tools like this are simply indispensable for techies and power users and you need to have one in your toolbelt. I know EaseUS (which you mentioned) offers a free version of a similar package as well. But to sum it up, your goal *is* achievable without having to purchase software.

Comment: Great very useful tool

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the built in windows tools cannot “move” data to resize partitions. Because your free space is not contiguous, you’ll need to use a 3rd party tool to resize the partitions. The tool will handle moving the physical data so that the partitions can be resized.

There are free choices available, just be careful with what you are downloading and always make sure you have a full, verified backup of your data before resizing partitions.

Comment: can we make unallocated space right to the C drive then my issue is solved?

Comment: Yes, delete the partition to the right of it.